# Updating ME21n fields WEORA/BSTAE via ME_PROCESS_PO_CUST BAdi?

Tags: abap, purchase-order, badi

I am trying to modify the values of `WEORA`, `BSTAE` in `ME21n` tcode upon saving. I've written the code in `ME_PROCESS_PO_CUST BADI`, method `CHECK`:

```
DATA: lt_data TYPE PURCHASE_ORDER_ITEMS,
      lo_header TYPE REF TO CL_PO_HEADER_HANDLE_MM,
      lt_item TYPE REF TO IF_PURCHASE_ORDER_ITEM_MM,
      ls_get_item TYPE MEPOITEM,
      ls_set_item TYPE MEPOITEM,
      lv_firewall TYPE abap_bool.

  FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_data> TYPE PURCHASE_ORDER_ITEM.

  lt_data = im_header->get_items( ).

  READ TABLE lt_data ASSIGNING <fs_data> INDEX 1.
  IF <fs_data> IS ASSIGNED.
    lt_item = <fs_data>-item.
  ENDIF.

  ls_get_item = lt_item->get_data( ).

  ls_get_item-bstae = '0004'.
  ls_get_item-weora = abap_true.


  CALL METHOD lt_item->set_data
    EXPORTING
      im_data = ls_get_item.
```

I tried debugging, but inside the method `set_data` there is a condition:

```
CHECK l_parent->my_ibs_firewall_on  EQ mmpur_yes OR
      l_parent->my_cust_firewall_on EQ mmpur_yes.
```

The value of both is initial so it interrupts and doesn't go to the rest of the code. Forced setting them to `true` makes all the code execute but update of the fields doesn't work anyway.

It seems that this BADI doesn't work but I made my research and most people use this BADI to update `EKPO` fields in `ME21n`.

Is there any problem with my code?

Is there other exit I can use to update fields `WEORA` and `BSTAE` in transaction code `ME21N` upon saving?

Comment: I don't think a `CHECK` method is used to change data. Try using the method `PROCESS_ITEM`, if you check the documentation it specifically says here that `The PROCESS_ITEM method enables you to change the item data and check it
for correctness.`

Comment: Hello @andrecito , I also tried transferring my code in the PROCESS_ITEM method but I got the endless loop error. I also tried the solutions I have searched regarding the error but none of them works properly. This solution was a close one http://saptechnical.com/Tutorials/ExitsBADIs/ME21N/Error.htm But after I input material, quantity, delivery date, plant and then press enter, The fields to be changed is updated but the values in material, quantity, delivery date and plant disappears.

Comment: Use `PROCESS_ITEM` method instead

Comment: @Suncatcher I already tried using PROCESS_ITEM method but it is also not working. I'm getting the error endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call method SET_DATAX and then SET_DATA.
  SET_DATAX , you will mark X to field you want to update values.

Regards,
Umar Abdullah

Comment: there is no set_datax method in class IF_PURCHASE_ORDER_ITEM_MM. The field is being updated in the screen. But  if I click the save button, the value is not reflecting in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `PROCESS_ITEM` method from this BAdi, your code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921599/ekpo-fields-not-updated-after-process-item-method-set-data-in-me21n) perfectly works for me and updates these fields:

```
DATA: ls_mepoitem_set TYPE mepoitem.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_item> TYPE mepoitem.

DATA(ls_mepoitem) = im_item->get_data( ).

ls_mepoitem_set = ls_mepoitem.
ls_mepoitem_set-bstae = '0004'.
ls_mepoitem_set-weora = abap_true.
ASSIGN ls_mepoitem_set TO <fs_item>.
CALL METHOD im_item->set_data( EXPORTING im_data = <fs_item> ).
```