# EKPO fields not updated after PROCESS_ITEM method set_data in ME21N

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I'm trying to change field WEORA and BSTAE in ME21n through BADI `me_process_po_cust`, method PROCESS_ITEM. I have successfully changed the value in the screen, BUT when I saved the PO, table EKPO is not updated with the new value. Am I missing something? Do I need to commit?

```
DATA: ls_mepoitem_set TYPE mepoitem.
DATA: cl_po TYPE REF TO cl_po_header_handle_mm.
DATA: ls_mepoitem TYPE mepoitem.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_item> TYPE mepoitem.

ls_mepoitem = im_item->get_data( ).
    
ls_mepoitem_set = ls_mepoitem.
ls_mepoitem_set-bstae = '0004'.
ls_mepoitem_set-weora = abap_true.
ASSIGN ls_mepoitem_set TO <fs_item>.
CALL METHOD im_item->set_data( EXPORTING im_data = <fs_item> ).
    
cl_po ?= lm_poheader.
IF NOT cl_po->my_recheck_queue IS INITIAL.
   CLEAR cl_po->my_recheck_queue.
ENDIF.
```

Comment: I add a reference to your first post about [updating the screen field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52877382/modifying-ekpo-fields-in-me21n-me-process-po-cust-badi), as it might be useful for understanding the context.

Comment: Please don't commit in this BADi. According to BADi documentation: `Under no circumstances make any changes to the database within this method. On no account use Commits.`

Comment: Is it possible that you didn't activated the BADi implementation?

Comment: The BADI implementation is activated because I'm debugging my code there. @NelsonMiranda

Comment: Your code works for me, check if you have conflicts with other BAdi implementations or other custom code

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is project enhancement implentation for PO which might be updating field values.

regards,
Umar Abdullha

Comment: But there is no set_datax method in class IF_PURCHASE_ORDER_ITEM_MM.

Comment: Yes. There is no method set_datax in PO. set_datax is in PR BAdi. I am updating answer.

Comment: I am using the BADI implementation of ME_PROCESS_PO_CUST. In the method PROCESS_ITEM. it updates the screen but when I click the save button, the value changed is not reflected in EKPO table

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mistake and I was able to resolve it by using the same code shown before in `IF_EX_ME_PROCESS_PO_CUST->PROCESS_ITEM`.

I had to call `im_item->get_data( )` to get the data from the position and the set method work perfectly.